# Sentry AJAX requests get 302 with Nginx and uWSGI

Tags: python, ajax, nginx, uwsgi, sentry

I have Sentry setup almost exactly like described [here](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/nginx.html).
My Sentry is available on `www.sentry.mysite.com:9000`, and everything working fine, except AJAX queries, for example by click on "resolve error" button. AJAX queries uses url without port, and they always get 302 status and they have no effect.

Kindly help.

Comment: What's the `SENTRY_URL_PREFIX` in your django settings.py?

Comment: @Leonardo.Z Thanks that was helped, if you post this is as an answer, I will accept.